# JndiLookup.class Still part of log4j-core-2.17.0.jar, is this expected?

Tags: logging, log4j, logstash, log4j2

I just downloaded log4j-core-2.17.0.jar and when I open it, I see "org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class" still part of the jar.

On apache security they have mentioned that -

Implement one of the following mitigation techniques:

Upgrade to Log4j 2.3.1 (for Java 6), 2.12.3 (for Java 7), or 2.17.0 (for Java 8 and later).
Otherwise, in any release other than 2.16.0, you may remove the JndiLookup class from the classpath: zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class

Is it like we have to download the JAR and then remove the jndi entry manually ? I thought in 2.16 and 2.17 log4j it was removed already.

Please clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4j2 2.17 still supports [JNDI lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html), so it needs the JndiLookup.class. 2.17 fixes the bugs related to JNDI lookups that allowed code execution (2.15) and Denial of Service (2.16). Deleting the JndiLookup.class from logstash converted a remote execution catastrophe to a class not found exception. It still potentially breaks logstash (DOS) but still a better result.